# MongoDB Deleting Documents

Tags: mongodb

So, I am using MongoDB to store a timer in each document created. Every second, it reduces the timer by 1 second. (using the updateMany function.) When the timer hits 0, it is supposed to delete the document. It does do that, however, if a document has a greater amount of time, it will wait for that document timer to finish first, putting the newer documents in the negatives, for example -25000 MS, and supposed to delete at 0.

Can anyone help me solve this, and delete any document that is less than or equal to 0 without it waiting for the prior documents to finish? Thank you!

````
  const schema = await giveaway.findOne();

  if (schema) {
    await giveaway.updateMany({
      $inc: {
        timer: -1000,
      },
    });
    if (schema.timer < 0) {
      const random = [...schema.userEntries].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
      const shuffle = random.slice(0, schema.giveawayOptions.winners);
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`${schema.ChannelID}`);
      const msg = await channel.messages.fetch(`${schema.MessageID}`);
      var newShuffle = [];
      shuffle.forEach((id) => {
        newShuffle.push([`<@${id}>`]);
      });
      msg.edit({
        embeds: [
          new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor({
              name: `${schema.giveawayOptions.prize}`,
              iconURL:
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1030899776423723171/1071213376644075640/MainGift.png",
            })
            .setDescription(
              `**•** This giveaway event has **ended!**\n\n${
                schema.userEntries.length >= 1
                  ? `Winners **•** ${newShuffle.join(", ")}`
                  : "**•** No participators!"
              }`
            )
            .setColor(client.mainColor),
        ],
        components: [],
      });
      await giveaway.findOneAndDelete();
    }
  }
}, 1 * 1000);```
````

Comment: "_if a document has a greater amount of time_". Your code starts by issuing a `findOne()` without a filter and then the subsequent `if()` conditional operates on the value in that document. You should apply predicate filters to find the document that you are interested in, for example the one with the lowest remaining time or something

Comment: why don't you use deleteMany with `{time : {$lt: 0}` filter?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the logic:

1. Update the timers
2. Retrieve and notify the `giveaway` with negative values
3. Delete the `giveaway` with negative values

```
await giveaway.updateMany({
  $inc: {
    timer: -1000,
  },
});

const negativeTimer = await giveaway.find({ timer: { $gte: 0 } });
for (const schema of negativeTimer) {
  const random = [...schema.userEntries].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  const shuffle = random.slice(0, schema.giveawayOptions.winners);
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get(`${schema.ChannelID}`);
  const msg = await channel.messages.fetch(`${schema.MessageID}`);
  var newShuffle = [];
  shuffle.forEach((id) => {
    newShuffle.push([`<@${id}>`]);
  });
  msg.edit({
    embeds: [
      new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setAuthor({
          name: `${schema.giveawayOptions.prize}`,
          iconURL:
            'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1030899776423723171/1071213376644075640/MainGift.png',
        })
        .setDescription(
          `**•** This giveaway event has **ended!**\n\n${
            schema.userEntries.length >= 1
              ? `Winners **•** ${newShuffle.join(', ')}`
              : '**•** No participators!'
          }`
        )
        .setColor(client.mainColor),
    ],
    components: [],
  });
}
await giveaway.deleteMany({ timer: { $gte: 0 } });
```

Anyway, be careful, executing `updateMany` and `deleteMany` every second can cause performance issues if the amount of data is large.